# Ubuntu OEM Installation (extracted iso) via PXE - preseed/late_command and ubiquity/success_command not working?

Tags: bash, pxe, preseed, ubiquity, oem

I set up a pxe-installation server using ubuntu server 16.04 for installing oem versions of ubuntu desktop 15.10, 16.04 and so on via pxe. The installations work fine, however, there's still one very important problem that I cannot seem to fix.

I want to execute a shell script after the installer finishes. The script cleans the network/interface file so the system has internet access after rebooting as well as upgrading and cleaning the system.

So far I've tried:

```
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target wget -O /root/tmp/postinstall.sh http://myserverip/postinst/postinstall.sh ; \
in-target chmod u+x /root/tmp/postinstall.sh ; \
in-target /bin/sh /root/tmp/postinstall.sh ; \
in-target rm /root/tmp/postinstall.sh

d-i preseed/late_command string in-target wget -O /root/tmp/postinstall.sh http://myserverip/postinst/postinstall.sh ; \
in-target chmod u+x /root/tmp/postinstall.sh ; \
in-target /bin/sh /root/tmp/postinstall.sh ; \
in-target rm /root/tmp/postinstall.sh
```

Neither works. Even, if I just try to create a simple file via touch, nothing happens.

Do OEM installations require a specific late_command in order to work. Or do I have to write a full preseed file so that it works? Right now, I just added the command to the default ubuntu.seed file that came with the iso.